# How can I tell a function of parent class is called by classmethod or instance method from child class?

Tags: python, oop

For instance:

```
class TestParent(object):
    # I need a function to be compatible with both classmethod and instance method.
    @property
    def log(cls, self=None):
        if "it's called from a child classmethod":
            return logging.root.getChild(cls.__class__.__module__ + '.' + cls.__class__.__name__)
        if "it's called from a child object":
            return logging.root.getChild(self.__class__.__module__ + '.' + self.__class__.__name__)



class TestChild(TestParent):
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        cls.logger.info('test')

    def test2(self):
        self.logger.info('test2')

child = TestChild()
child.test()
child.test2()
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like what you want by using a `staticmethod` instead of a property, passing the caller's `cls` or `self` and testing whether it's a class object or not:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class TestParent(object):
    # I need a function to be compatible with both classmethod and instance method.
    @staticmethod
    def logger(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, type):
            return logging.root.getChild(obj.__class__.__module__ + '.' + obj.__class__.__name__)
        else:
            return logging.root.getChild(obj.__class__.__module__ + '.' + obj.__class__.__name__)
```

Output:

```
INFO:builtins.type:test
INFO:__main__.TestChild:test2
```

Having said that, it's more usual in Python to define a module per logger rather than per class.  Unless there is real value to be gained from having per-class loggers I'd go with one per module.

Comment: Hi, if using staticmethod, should I call `cls.logger().info` instead of `cls.logger.info()` ? can I omit `()`, being like as a  property

Comment: I don't think so: a property lookup in the class `__dict__` will return the property itself rather than its value.  Also, you need some way to pass the message to the logger.